# regular expression pattern for any string with specific length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to build pattern for preg_match that will match any string with length 1 - 40 chars. I found this:

```
^[^<\x09]{1,40}\Z
```

But with that one I recieve this error message:

```
function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '<' in ....
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: That is not something you should use regex for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/^.{1,40}$/` should match any string that's 1 to 40 characters long.

What it does is that it takes the `.`, which matches everything, and repeats it 1 to 40 times (`{1,40}`). The `^` and `$` are anchors at the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care what the characters are, you don't need regex. Use [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) to test the length of a string:

```
if ((strlen($yourString) <= 40) && (strlen($yourString) >= 1)) {

}
```

This will be *far* faster than booting up the PCRE engine.

---

Addendum: if your string may contain multi-byte characters (e.g. **`é`**), you should use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php), which takes these characters into consideration.